# Batch script variable not working right

Tags: windows, batch-file

Well... I try to dabble in batch as little as possible, and I'm mainly a C/C#/C++ man. My problem is that my script does two nested FOR loops where I run through the 'Users' folder first and snag the user names and then through other folders:

```
 set BaseDir=%CD%
 cd C:\Users
 for /F %%I in ('DIR *.* /B /O:-D') do (
     set UserName=%%I
     echo %UserName%
 )
 cd %BaseDir%
```

This roughly demonstrates the problem. Maybe it's my C++ style formatting? Maybe I'm dumb when it comes to batch? Assuming I have 3 users on my system (Admin, User1, User2; in that order) this will print:

```
 Admin
 Admin
 Admin
```

Totes wrong. If one were to call echo on %%I everything would go according to plan:

```
 Admin
 User1
 User2
```

Am I missing something here as far as variables go, or what's the deal? DOS doesn't like variable re-assignment? 
Thnx in advance. (specs: Windows 7, notepad, cmd as admin)

Comment: You might be having a conflict with the predefined username variable. What happens if you change that variable from UserName to UserName2 (or similar)

Comment: Wut? I actually just solved my problem *facepalm*. The solution is ["elusive"](http://blog.crankybit.com/why-that-batch-for-loop-isnt-working/). One has to set Delayed Expansion... basically, it's like we're back in 1969...

Comment: I believe me saying the answer in my head telepathically went to you while I was typing my answer 0.o

Comment: Also note that you should use cd /D or pushd instead of just cd.  The code as written won't work if C isn't the current drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are changing a variable within the `FOR` loop, you need to enable delayed expansions:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd C:\Users
for /F %%I in ('DIR *.* /B /O:-D') do (
 set UserName=%%I
 echo %UserName%
)
```

EDIT
A neat way to assign the variables separately to access each instance outside of the loop

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
    cd C:\Users
    for /F %%I in ('DIR *.* /B /O:-D') do (
     set UserName!count!=%%I
     echo %UserName!count!%
     set count=!count!+1
    )
```

Comment: Indeed, I stumbled on this conclusion almost immediately after I posted... This should be something posted under the documentation. It's bound to be something everyone has to learn once.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a subroutine:

```
 pushd C:\Users
 for /F %%I in ('DIR *.* /B /O:-D') do call :perfile %%I
 popd
 goto :eof

 :perfile
 set UserName=%*
 echo %UserName%
 goto :eof
```

Also note the use of pushd and popd to avoid needing to store the original directory in an environment variable.